# Laravel 5, PHPUnit not logging to console

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5

I'm new to `Laravel 5` and it seems PHP Unit is logging unit test errors inside `app/storage/*.log`, which is nice, but I'd like to know if there's a way to log them right into console, or any faster method than re-opening/re-syncing said `*.log` file each time a test fail (as I'm trying extreme programming, lotta test fails).

Comment: That shouldn't be the case unless you are running PHPUnit through Laravel?

Comment: What errors are we exactly talking about?

Comment: The errors are usually crashes that leads to error 500 and they get logged on those files (for example an attempt to call a method on a null object crashes the program).

Comment: Well then that's totally normal. What you can do (in a linux terminal) is run `tail -f laravel.log` so you can see changes in your log file immediately.

Comment: oh thats true, can you write it as an answer so I can mark it please?